# How can I fix the error "Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id from facebook API"?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking how fix the error. This error seems quite common, on searching for it I found lots of topics as it this here, but with no reply.

I tried the following code:

Permissions:

```
$post['req_perms'] = 'user_photos,friends_photos,publish_stream';
```

and:

```
 $photo_id = '246593408718864';
  $to_user_id =  'my friend id';
  $args = array('x' => 50, 
          'y' => 50,
    );
  $facebook->api("/{$photo_id}/tags?to={$to_user_id}", 'POST', $args);
```

and getting the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id
  thrown in E:\etc\src\base_facebook.php on line 1033
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

the error has explained the case already.
you are passing an invalid photo id.

using a correct photo id will solve the problem... at least this never happens to me